# javascript hide/show fails in ie8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following javascript

```
function hide(id)
{
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    if ((ele.style.display == 'none') || (ele.style.display == '')) {
    try{
     ele.style.display = 'table-row';
     }
     catch (e)
     {
     ele.style.display='block';
     }}
    else {ele.style.display = 'none';}
}
```

which works in ie7, chrome, ff, but fails in ie8

I have to get it to work in ie8 even if it fails in chrome or ff.

I believe the issue is `'ele.style.display = 'table-row'`

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'? The `try` statement should catch any error on that and set `display` to `block`?

Comment: Relying on a browser to throw an exception because "table-row" is not a valid "display" value for some elements is not a good idea in the first place, because it's *not* invalid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
function toggle(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == "none" || el.style.display == "") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: Because blindly setting something to "display: block" isn't a good idea. What if it should be "display: inline"? Or "display: table-cell"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are experiencing as a failure in IE8, but you might change in your `if` this:

```
ele.style.display == ''
```

to this:

```
ele.style.display == undefined
```